# How to provide role saved in DB as GrantedAuthority in UserDetails implementation?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a `UserDetail` implementation -

```
class AuthUserDetails(val user: UserEntity): UserDetails {

    override fun getAuthorities(): Collection<GrantedAuthority?>? {
        return listOf(SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"))
    }

    override fun getPassword(): String? {
        return user.password
    }

    override fun getUsername(): String? {
        return user.userName
    }

    override fun isEnabled(): Boolean {
        return user.isActive
    }

    override fun isAccountNonExpired(): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun isAccountNonLocked(): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun isCredentialsNonExpired(): Boolean {
        return true
    }
}
```

My UserEntity is as follows -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
class UserEntity(@Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
                 @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
                 var id: Long = 0,
                 @Column(name = "user_roles", nullable = false)
                 var roles: String = "admin")
```

As you can see I have hard coded the return type of `getAuthorities()` as "ROLE_ADMIN". However, I would want to pick the role saved in the DB under `user_roles` columns and provide that as `SimpleGrantedAuthority`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to do that? `SimpleGrantedAuthority` is a spring security class and not a good idea to mix with your domain model. Anyway you can do it like this.

- Write a jpa `AttributeConverter` for `SimpleGrantedAuthority`

```
    import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;

    import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
    import javax.persistence.Converter;
    import java.util.Optional;

    @Converter
    public class SimpleGrantedAuthorityConverter implements
        AttributeConverter<SimpleGrantedAuthority, String> {

      @Override
      public String convertToDatabaseColumn(SimpleGrantedAuthority authority) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(authority)
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .orElse(null);
      }

      @Override
      public SimpleGrantedAuthority convertToEntityAttribute(String role) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(role)
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .orElse(null);
       }
    }
```

- Annotate the field in the `UserEntity` with `equivalent` of :

```
     @Convert(converter = SimpleGrantedAuthorityConverter.class)
     private SimpleGrantedAuthority role;
```

**Note**

Spring secuirty's design, a user can have multiple roles but I noted your are storing only single role. I assume that is your business case.

Comment: I was following this tutorial - https://github.com/koushikkothagal/spring-security-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/io/javabrains/springsecurityjpa/models/MyUserDetails.java

In this he stores all the roles in one column but comma separated. Then he splits them in the `UserDetails` impl. Is there something I have misunderstood?

Comment: If you are storing comma separated list, the solution above won't work.  He is doing that for tutorial. But normally you will have 3 tables instead of one. `User` table, `Role` table and `UserRole` table.  Anyway even if you store it as single comma separated string, you can use this method to get list of authorities `AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(commaSepratedString)`

Comment: What is the use of `UserRole` table?

Comment: A particular `User` can have many `Role`s,  A particular `Role` may be associated with many `User`s  so the relationship between them is  `many to many` so in relational world, you need a association table to keep the `many to many` relationship