# error:org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-security

I'm using Spring security from Spring boot to create a login page.
I have entered the correct username and password, but when I try to log in I get the error:

> org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException.

I am using DB (MySQL) and JPA.

MySQL settings:

[image]

Here is all the source code.
https://github.com/kiki202181/LoginTest

**WebSecurityConfig**

```
package login.app.config;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login") 
                .loginProcessingUrl("/sign_in") 
                .usernameParameter("username") 
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .successForwardUrl("/hello")
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .permitAll();
    }
    
    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

}
```

**LoginController**

```
package login.app.controller;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    List<UserForm> UserList;

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    private String init() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

**UserForm**

```
package login.app.entity;

@Setter
@Getter
@Entity(name = "User")
@Table(name = "user_tb")
public class UserForm {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private GrantedAuthority authority;
}
```

**UserRepository**

```
package login.app.repository;
import login.app.entity.UserForm;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserForm, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM user_tb", nativeQuery = true)
    List<UserForm> findAllUser();

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM user_tb WHERE name=?1", nativeQuery = true)
    List<UserForm> findByname(String name);

}
```

**UserDetailsServiceImpl**

```
package login.app.service;

@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        List<UserForm> userList = userRepository.findByname(username);
        UserForm userForm = userList.get(0);

        String dbUserName = userForm.getName();

        if (dbUserName == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not authorized.");
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> grantList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        GrantedAuthority authority = userForm.getAuthority();
        grantList.add(authority);

        BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        String password = encoder.encode(userForm.getPassword());

        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) new User(username, password, grantList);
        return userDetails;
    }

}
```

**login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div th:if="${param.logout}">
            You have been logged out.
    </div>
    <div th:if="${param.error}">
            Invalid username and password.
    </div>
    

    <form th:action="@{/sign_in}" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="username">user_name
        <br/>
        <input type="password" name="password">password
        
        <br/>
        
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Error code**

```
An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.

org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:108) ~[spring-security-core-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:133) ~[spring-security-core-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:222) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:132) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:331) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy87.findByname(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at login.app.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(UserDetailsServiceImpl.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:93) ~[spring-security-core-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    ... 57 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:29) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3131) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1863) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.hydrateEntityState(Loader.java:1791) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1764) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1616) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:740) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowsFromResultSet(Loader.java:1039) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:990) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:959) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2843) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2825) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2657) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2652) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2141) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1169) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1604) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:126) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:159) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 55534552
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:963) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:397) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:309) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:299) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add Granted authority converter.
Refer the following link
[How to provide role saved in DB as GrantedAuthority in UserDetails implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63175212/how-to-provide-role-saved-in-db-as-grantedauthority-in-userdetails-implementatio)

Add the below code in UserDetails loadUserByUsername method

```
if (null == userList || userList.isEmpty() ) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found");
        }
```

Comment: I added this code. But I got the same error code.

Comment: Did you tried the first answer in the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63175212/how-to-provide-role-saved-in-db-as-grantedauthority-in-userdetails-implementatio

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this error is that I am did not running the "new Simple Granted Authority".

```
Collection <GrantedAuthority> grantList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
```

I had to do a `new Simple Granted Authority` before I could put it in the list in the grantList.

**UserDetailsServiceImpl**

```
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        List<UserForm> userList = userRepository.findByname(username);
        UserForm userForm = userList.get(0);

        if (null == userList || userList.isEmpty() ) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found");
        }
        
        String dbUserName = userForm.getName();

        if (dbUserName == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not authorized.");
        }
                
        Collection <GrantedAuthority> grantList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userForm.getAuthority());

        grantList.add(authority);

        BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        String password = encoder.encode(userForm.getPassword());

        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) new User(username, password, grantList);
        return userDetails;
    }

}
```

Changed the type of authority (UserForm class) to String.

**UserForm**

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity(name = "User")
@Table(name = "user_tb")
public class UserForm {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String authority;
```

I also tried case using the convert class.
In that case, change the type of authority (UserForm class) to "simpleGrantedAuthority".

**UserForm**

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity(name = "User")
@Table(name = "user_tb")
public class UserForm {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String password;
//  private String authority;
        
    @Convert(converter = SimpleGrantedAuthorityConverter.class)
    private SimpleGrantedAuthority authority;
}
```

**SimpleGrantedAuthorityConverter**

```
package login.app.converter;

import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;

@Converter
public class SimpleGrantedAuthorityConverter implements AttributeConverter<SimpleGrantedAuthority, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(SimpleGrantedAuthority authority) {
        // (Entity→DB)

        if (authority == null) {
            return "USER";
        }

        String dbData = authority.toString();

        return dbData;

    }

    @Override
    public SimpleGrantedAuthority convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        //(Entity←DB)

        if (dbData == null) {
            SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER");
            return authority;
        }

        SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(dbData);

        return authority;
    }

}
```

**UserDetailsServiceImpl**

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        List<UserForm> userList = userRepository.findByname(username);
        UserForm userForm = userList.get(0);

        if (null == userList || userList.isEmpty() ) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found");
        }
        
        String dbUserName = userForm.getName();

        if (dbUserName == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not authorized.");
        }
                
        Collection <GrantedAuthority> grantList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        
        grantList.add(userForm.getAuthority());

        BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        String password = encoder.encode(userForm.getPassword());

        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) new User(username, password, grantList);
        return userDetails;
    }

}
```